# What does MBRContains and MBRWithin test? What does "contains" and "within" mean?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, spatial, terminology

`MBRContains(g1, g2)` is defined as,

> Returns `1` or `0` to indicate whether the minimum bounding rectangle of g1 contains the minimum bounding rectangle of g2. This tests the opposite relationship as `MBRWithin()`.

`MBRWithin(g1, g2)` is defined as,

> Returns `1` or `0` to indicate whether the minimum bounding rectangle of g1 is within the minimum bounding rectangle of g2. This tests the opposite relationship as `MBRContains()`.

What exactly does `contains` and `within` mean in that context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [`DE-91M` (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) terms, and they were [standardized with Simple Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Features)

but, Wikipedia probably covers it best, with two definitions,

> - `a` contains `b`: geometry `b` lies in `a`, and the interiors intersect.
> - `a` contains `b` iff no points of `b` lie in the exterior of `a`, and at least one point of the interior of `b` lies in the interior of `a`

The *within* relationship is the inverse of *contains*, with one catch *"polygons do not contain their boundary."* Other than that, `within(a,b) = contains(b,a)`. [Though interestingly, linestrings do *contain* all the points along the linestrings, except the terminal points.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/295064/6052)

For more information see the Wikipedia,

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM